# Failed to load JavaHL Library when opening Eclipse

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, svn, ubuntu

What does mean this when I open Eclipse?

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

I can't even commit my work in SVN. I get:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E160013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160013: '/svn/XXX/src' path not found: 404 Not Found (https://...)
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E160013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E160013: '/svn/XXX/src' path not found: 404 Not Found (https://...)
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to solve the problem is to re-install subclipse! seems there is some issue in your JavaHL libraries which is required by subclipse to work with SVN.

Update site for subclipse:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x/

Answer (score 0):

basically what I did was:
copy the class content to text file
remove this class from project
commit changes to SVN
then create "new" class and commit.